# Date Range with ion-range-slider not working in angular

Tags: angular, ion-range-slider

**I am trying to implement a simple date range slider using [ion-range-slider](https://github.com/PhilippStein/ng2-ion-range-slider) in angular**

**This is the html**

```html
<ion-range-slider #sliderElement
          type="double"
          [min]="myMinVar"
          [max]="myMaxVar"></ion-range-slider>
```

**Component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']

})
export class AppComponent {
  myMinVar:Date;
  myMaxVar:Date;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myMaxVar = new Date(2018,2,2);
    this.myMinVar = new Date(2012,2,2);
  }
}
```

[image]

**When i try to change the range i am getting NAN**

[image]

**can any one let me know how can i fix the above issue**
**Or is there any other third party date range slider i can use in angular?**

Comment: Did you solve it?